# How does Spring Data decide what is returned by FindBy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

**How does Spring Data's findBy decide which database record to return if there are multiple matches?**

I realised if I have more than one entry in my Elastic Search database with the same attribute code (ie: "123"), Spring only returns one entry when I call a 'findByAttributeCode'.

If I use a findById, its self explanatory as Id's are unique, however with other findBys, there can be many matches. *Note: attributeCode is NOT unique.*

How does Spring decide which one to return?

My call would be something like this:
`Attribute attribute = findByAttribute(attributeCode);`

The repo would look like this:

```
public interface AttributeRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Attribute, String> {
    
    Attribute findByAttributeCode(String attributeCode);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from the return type that you define for your function. If you specify a collection, all matching documents are returned for your query.

If you define a single object as return type, the first entry returned from the underlying store - here Elasticsearch - is returned. What this first entry is, depends on your query criteria, sort parameters - whatever Elasticsearch  returns first, is returned to the caller.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish I could accept both you and franks answers at the same time.

Comment: Well, actually I answered your question "How does Spring decide". Frank showed you how to get all, that in the strict sense no answer to your question

Comment: Cute... teach a man to fish... Good grief @P.J.Meisch

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing, if there are more than one possibility is creating the method stub like this:

```
<Iterable>Attribute findByAttributeCode(String attributeCode);
```

This way you return them all. If you don't do that, you are beholden to the RDBMS in how it builds it swap to return a single entry from the multiple tuples it will return from the query it builds, which should be something like:

```
select * from table where attributeCode = ?;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Frank, this clears things up!